# need a little explanation about references and variable copies (C#)

Tags: c#, reference

how can this be cleanly refactored:

```
  private MyType a;
  private MYType b;
  private MyType c;
  ...
  public void MyMT(MyEnum myEnum)
     {
        switch(myEnum)
        {
        case myEnum.a:
        a=Method(a);
        break;
        case myEnum.b:
        b=Method(b);
        break;
        case myEnum.c:
        c=Method(c);
        break;
        }

    }
```

I had in mind something like this:

```
  public void MyMT(MyEnum myEnum)
     {
        MyType _myType;

        switch(myEnum)
        {
        case myEnum.a:
        _myType =a;
        break;
        case myEnum.b:
        _myType =b;
        break;
        case myEnum.c:
        _myType =c;
        break;
        }
        _myType = Method(_myType);
    }
```

`_myType` being an obect, I thought that

```
_myType=a;
```

would copy "a" 's address into myType so that when I later modify _myType value, it would also modify "a" value.
_myType gets the correct value when this line is hit:

```
 _myType = Method(_myType);
```

but a (or b or c) is not updated as I thought.

Aren't references supposed to work this way??

EDIT:
Method actually creates a SQL connection, calling:

```
Method(MyType _myType)
{
 new MySqlConnection(_myType.ToString());
}
```

Comment: yes if you modify mytype like `mytype.prop = something` it works and not changing the reference again like `mytype = something`... also mytype must be a class not struct. can you show code for `Method`

Comment: I detailed Method() in edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign `_myType=a` you reference `a` through `_myType`. When you then do `_myType = Method(_myType)` you simply store a new reference in `_myType`. Your `Method` should directly modify your object's properties if you want to mutate it.

Comment: OK I got it. Thank you Manuel.

Comment: how MySqlConnection object is passed to MyType reference?? is MyType base class of MySqlConnection class??